# Ubuntu Phone to be instal on a samsung device

Tags: samsung

Can i instal ubuntu on my Samsung Galaxy S Advance? If yes, what are the procedures?

Comment: What sort of Ubuntu version do you want to install? Plain Ubuntu or Ubuntu touch?

Answer (score 0):

The list of currently supported devices along with links to the install procedure can be found here...
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Unfortunately the Samasung Galaxy S Advance isn't supported at the moment although this may change in the future.